# ReactJS doesn't accept a render with mapped array to a template

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In a react component I'm  mapping a simple array to a component, for instance:

```
render() {
    return <div>10</div>
}
```

Code above works fine, but the following doesn't work:

```
render() {
    var array = [1,2,3,4]
    return array.map((i) =><div key={i}>{i}</div>)
}
```

However if I surround it with a `<div>` tag it works.

```
render() {
    var array = [1,2,3,4]
    return <div>{ array.map((i) =><div key={i}>{i}</div>)}</div>
}
```

How can I avoid using the `<div>` tag and still get this to work?

Comment: Until the latest React version you must return a single element (which may contain arbitrary children). So you either upgrade React, or you work within the way your version works.

Comment: you cant, you need a top level element unless your upgrade to react 16.0+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are not on React v16 yet. Before React v16 you couldn't return an array of elements: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings

That is why you must wrap your return with a `div` or another single element.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a React version older than `16.x.x`, the render method doesn’t support returning more than one child. You return one child by wrapping the code in your return with a `<div></div>` or `<ul></ul>`.
You may simply need to install the newer version of React.

Comment: React 16+ does. (Nor does the wrapper need to be a `<div>` but I assume you were using that as an example.)